# Получить доступ к контейнеру объекта

Tags: jquery

```
<div> <!-container!>
    <input type="search" name="query"> <!-object!>
</div>
```

Как при фокусе на объект выполнить `addClass('is-focused')` для контейнера-родителя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть острая необходимость именно для такого HTML записать код и нет вариантов туда добавить классы и id...

Есть такой вариант:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/8m2fn9qj/)

```js
$('input[name="query"]').on('focusin', function(){ $(this).parent().addClass('is-focused');});

$('input[name="query"]').on('focusout', function(){ $(this).parent().removeClass('is-focused');});
```

```css
.is-focused {border: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="search" name="query">
</div>
```

Еще была такая версия, но preventDefault(); выдает ошибку, и пока не понимаю почему (хотя сам эффект почему-то работает):

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/4jm9rosy/)

```js
//При клике в любом месте на странице - убираем класс.
$(document).on('click', function(){
  $('input[name="query"]').parent().removeClass('is-focused');
});

//При клике на сам инпут - добавляем класс на его родителя
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="query"]', function(e){
  $('input[name="query"]').parent().addClass('is-focused');
  //но отключаем оттуда все остальные клики: Сам инпут тоже находится
  //на странице и кликая на него - должен был сработать и клик на страницу)
  e.preventDefult();
});
```

```css
.is-focused {border: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="search" name="query">
</div>
```

Comment: У Вас ошибка в коде, посмотрите, пожалуйста. `e` (Hint)

Comment: Доп. подскзка: `function(e) { e.preventDefault() }`